# Changing A* to dijkstra's

Tags: algorithm

```
function A*(start, goal)

closedSet := {}

openSet := {start}

cameFrom := an empty map

gScore := map with default value of Infinity

gScore[start] := 0

fScore := map with default value of Infinity

fScore[start] := heuristic_cost_estimate(start, goal)

while openSet is not empty
    current := the node in openSet having the lowest fScore[] value
    if current = goal
        return reconstruct_path(cameFrom, current)

    openSet.Remove(current)
    closedSet.Add(current)

    for each neighbor of current
        if neighbor in closedSet
            continue    

        if neighbor not in openSet  
            openSet.Add(neighbor)

        tentative_gScore := gScore[current] + dist_between(current, neighbor)
        if tentative_gScore >= gScore[neighbor]
            continue        

        cameFrom[neighbor] := current
        gScore[neighbor] := tentative_gScore
        fScore[neighbor] := gScore[neighbor] + heuristic_cost_estimate(neighbor, goal) 

return failure

function reconstruct_path(cameFrom, current)
total_path := [current]
while current in cameFrom.Keys:
    current := cameFrom[current]
    total_path.append(current)
return total_path
```

If I were to take this A* alorgithim and instead of taking the lowest fScore from openset, take the lowest gscore and not even consider the fScore would that effectively make this dijksta's?

Answer (score 2):

Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm is a special case for A* in which the heuristic is zero although Dijkstra's algorithm (1958) was conceived before 10 years. A* greedily chooses which vertex to look next during search according to `f(v)`, where `f(v) = h(v) + g(v)`. If you set the heuristic (`h(v)`) to zero, A* becomes to choose vertices considering only the current cost (`g(v)`), and you achieve to transform informed A* into non-informed Dijkstra.

In short, my answer to your question is "Yes".

Comment: And dijksta's should find the absolute shortest route right? I only wanted to change my algorithim from A* since it was finding a very short, but not the absolute shortest route, and after both changes, either making it use gScore or making the cost estimate 0 it still finds the same almost shortest route

Comment: A* finds the shortest path if your heuristic is a proper lower bound of the actual cost. Since 0 is a proper lower bound for any positive cost, this is also unconditionally true for Dijkstra.

Comment: I agree with @NicoSchertler. In general, A* is faster, since we look the vertices according to a heuristic this time. But it can be worse depending on the complexity of the heuristic. If you use the proper heuristic it's possible to be sure that your A* algorithm finds the shortest path. Check this: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/63089/a-star-pathfinding-not-giving-shortest-path

Comment: It's not only **possible** that A* finds the shortest path, it's **guaranteed** if you choose a heuristic satisfying the condition of never being greater than the really remaining distance.

Comment: I said "it's possible to be sure" actually. :D A very indirect way of saying "guaranteed". What I mean is if you use the satisfying heuristic, it's possible, and otherwise, it's not.

Comment: @user3645925 `A* does not find absolute shortest path` even if heuristic is not admissible then still A* finds the shortest path but it's not efficient. A* stops when all the nodes in queue have cost higher than the cost of founded path.